# How can I have a drop-shadow when hovering <li>s that overlaps its siblings elements?

Tags: styles, css

I’ve set the `<li>` tags in a list to have a drop shadow when hovered. However, for all but the last `<li>`, the shadow is partially hidden by the next `<li>` element. See my example JSFiddle:

```
- http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/B9gn2/
```

I need the shadow to appear on top of the sibling `<li>`s, like the last `<li>` already does. How can I achieve that?

Comment: can u elaborate it ple..

Comment: a fixed fiddle is on my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/B9gn2/1/

Position the `<li>`s relatively, give them a z-index of 1 when hover state is active, and 0 when not. This layers the shadows on top of one another.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That’s the stuff: working code, and explained better than I did.

Comment: Paul thnx! It's the same what I need.

Comment: Hi again, 1 bug, it doesn't work with IE8 and I've got a trouble.